# Is Vue's @error on img tag listening for the onerror event?

Tags: vue.js

I've run into an issue where I need to use a fallback image in the event that an image's `src` attribute can't be found. Most of the advice I've seen on this regarding Vue is to use `@error`:

```
<img src="badsrc.jpg" @error="handleError" />
```

This works great. My `handleError` logic runs when the image 404's and I'm able to set a data prop on the component that a computed property then uses to detect that the image source needs to use a fallback image. But I've noticed that according to MDN (Mozilla Developer Network), the `onerror` attribute on an `img` tag is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Additionally, IE11 support for `onerror` is unknown (luckily that browser should be officially retired this November).

Does that mean I shouldn't be using `@error` on an `img` in Vue, or is `@error` really doing something else behind the scenes? I noticed that my compiled HTML doesn't have an `onerror` attribute for the image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works as expected:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      src: '/src.png',
      backupSrc: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300.png/09f/fff',
      didLoad: true,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    pictureLoadingError() {
      this.didLoad = false;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" v-cloak>
  <div>
    <img v-if="didLoad" :src="src" @error="pictureLoadingError" />
    <img v-else :src="backupSrc" />
  </div>
</div>
```

### MDN Deprecation

It looks like the chart is a bit misleading. The spec was deprecated from the `img` tag attributes and effectively moved into a global `GlobalEventHandlers` spec.

That can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror

Where you can see that it does not have the deprecation icon in the chart at the end of the page.